# Storing secrets in GAE Flex environment, making it easy to work with in local/dev env

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible, google-cloud-platform

This is for GAE **Flex** Env, application written in Go.

Two parts to the question:

1. Where is it idiomatic to store application **secrets** such as **passwords/keys** to connect to other services? In Heroku for example they are env vars. But in GAE **Flex** you can't put them in app.yaml because that file has other config settings in it and it normally gets stored in git.
   Some ideas: Metadata service, Datastore, GCS bucket ... but see next question.
2. How do you deal with local application testing? To use Heroku as an example again, you can create a local .env file. Getting the setting at runtime is consistent, you just read env vars. How do you make this easy to use with GAE Flex? Any Go utilities/libraries out there that abstract local env vs. GAE Flex "production" env? Of course, there are usually (at least) 3 envs: local/dev, staging, production.